# extending Phaser.js classes

Tags: javascript, oop, phaser-framework

im working with Phaser framework , i want to create new class that hold all properties from sprite class in phaser so i tried doing this

```
var mario = function(){

    Phaser.Sprite.call(this); // inherit from sprite
};
```

but there was an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

then i tried

```
var mario = function(){

   this.anything = "";

};

mario.prototype = new Phaser.Sprite();
```

OK it works but it called phaser constructor and i don't want to create sprite until i do `var heroObj = new mario();`

what should i do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this. I added a namespace to avoid global variables.

```
var YourGameNSpace = YourGameNSpace || {};

YourGameNSpace.Mario = function (game) {
    'use strict';

    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game);
};

// add a new object Phaser.Sprite as prototype of Mario 
YourGameNSpace.Mario.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
// specify the constructor
YourGameNSpace.Mario.constructor = YourGameNSpace.Mario;

//add new method
YourGameNSpace.Mario.prototype.init = function () {
    'use strict';
    ...
};
```

And after you can instantiate it:

```
var mario = new YourGameNSpace.Mario(game);
```

Comment: thanks it works but can you explain what "Object.create" exactly do

Comment: "_The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties._" - [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) -  And this post helps understand prototype. [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 5):

This is much easier now with ES6, for example:

```
export default class CustomSprite extends Phaser.Sprite {
    constructor(game){
        super(game, 0, 0);
        this.addChild(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'someSprite'));
        game.stage.addChild(this);
    }
    update() {
        //move/rotate sprite
    }
}
```

You can then import and use it like this:

```
this.customSprite = new CustomSprite(this.game);
this.customSprite.x = 400;
this.customSprite.y = 100;
```

Here´s a boilerplate to get you started: https://github.com/belohlavek/phaser-es6-boilerplate/

Comment: What is purpose of `this.addChild(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'someSprite'))`? In my case this line creates second sprite.

Comment: that´s just an example of adding another sprite to the custom sprite. you can also just remove it.

Comment: is possible get `game` inside the extended class without passing it inside the `new` method?

Comment: this is very old code, you would rather add it to a scene instead of a game now. and you actually don´t need to keep the reference, because "this.scene" would return the scene of the sprite.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small set of JS utilities, including inheritance with (potentially even abstract) classes:

```
var Unit = squishy.extendClass(Phaser.Sprite, 
function (game, x, y, sprite, ...) {
    // ctor

    // Call the the base (Sprite) ctor
    this._super(game, x, y, sprite);

    // ...
},{
    // methods
    update: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

If you are interested, [you can see the result of applying it to Phaser's "Sprite Demo 2" in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywzmkso3/17/).